# É possível realizar um "prepend" em um atributo?

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho a seguinte situação: Quando realizo a requisição do meu banco, minhas tags `<img>` já vem com o atributo `src` preenchido, é possível eu realizar um `prepend` no mesmo?

Por exemplo: `<img src="meuArquivo.jpg">`, e via jQuery eu inserir o caminho anterior ao "meuArquivo.jpg"?

Entendo como algo assim:

```
var meuCaminho = "C:/"
$('img').attr('src').prepend(meuCaminho);
```

Mas acho que não é funcional.

Comment: Não entendi. Primeiro, o `src` da imagem não pode ser desse jeito. E segundo, coloque um exemplo de como que você quer que fica seu `img`.

Comment: editei a pergunta, da uma olhada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não precisa usar `prepend`.

```
var imagem = $('img').attr('src');
var meuCaminho = "C:/"

$('img').attr('src', meuCaminho + imagem);
```

Comment: funcionou, agradeço a atenção